# python symbol can be global and local in the same scope

Tags: python, global-variables, symbols

Consider this function:

```
def content(path):
  global file # not useful but valid
  with open(path) as file:
    return file.read()
```

When generating a symbol table (using module `symtable`) and inspecting the symbol `file` in the scope of the function `content`, it is global and local at the same time. After calling this function the global name `file` is bound to the file object. So I wonder why the symbol `file` in the function scope is also considered as a local symbol?

Here is code to reproduce the behaviour (put it in a file e.g. called `global_and_local.py`):

```
import symtable

def content(path):
  global file
  with open(path) as file:
    return file.read()

symtable_root = symtable.symtable(content(__file__), __file__, "exec")
symtable_function = symtable_root.get_children()[0]
symbol_file = symtable_function.lookup('file')
print("symbol 'file' in function scope: is_global() =", symbol_file.is_global())
print("symbol 'file' in function scope: is_local() =", symbol_file.is_local())
print("global scope: file =", file)
```

The following output is generated:

```
symbol 'file' in function scope: is_global() = True
symbol 'file' in function scope: is_local() = True
global scope: file = <_io.TextIOWrapper name='global_and_local.py' ...>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For some reason, `symtable` [defines](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.8.2/Lib/symtable.py#L199) `is_local` as a check for whether any binding operations for a symbol occur in the scope (or annotations, which are lumped together with annotated assignments at this stage):

```
def is_local(self):
    return bool(self.__flags & DEF_BOUND)
```

rather than a check for whether the symbol is actually local, which would look like

```
def is_local(self):
    return bool(self.__scope in (LOCAL, CELL))
```

I'm not sure why. This might be a bug. I don't think modules like this get much use - [it took over a year](https://devguide.python.org/grammar/) before anyone [noticed](https://bugs.python.org/issue676521) that adding the `//` operator broke the old `parser` module, so I could easily see this going unnoticed.

Comment: @coproc: Assignment, function definitions, imports, use as a `for` loop target, etc. Anything that would rebind a name.

Comment: I have committed a bug report (see https://bugs.python.org/issue40196 ) and referred to your answer

Comment: symtable.Symbol.is_local() is fixed now: https://github.com/python/cpython/pull/19391

Comment: Ah, whoops. `Python/symtable.c` handles `CELL` a bit differently from other scopes, so I didn't realize it was a separate option from `LOCAL`. I'm pretty sure the `bool` is redundant, though (although it's not redundant in some of the other methods that perform an `&`).

Comment: I'm glad somebody else caught that, so we didn't just go from one bug to another.